# SQL Server : procedure throwing batch error

Tags: sql-server

Writing a procedure with condition if the cell has NULL value than add whatever the Variable has but if it already has value then leave its original value/don't overwrite it.

This is an update procedure.

Here is my query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[Learning]
    @StartDate NVARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @EndDate   NVARCHAR(20) = NULL,
    @Data      NVARCHAR(20) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) T1.CID  
               FROM temp.dbo.TABLE1 AS T1 
               WHERE StartDate = @StartDate)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE temp.dbo.TABLE1
        SET StartDate = ISNULL(@StartDate, StartDate),
            EndDate = ISNULL(@EndDate, EndDate),
            Data = ISNULL(@Data, Data)
        WHERE TABLE1.SSC = 'OP'
    END
```

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE temp.dbo.Table1
(
     CID INT,
     PID INT,
     SSC VARCHAR(3),
     StartDate VARCHAR(20),
     EndDate VARCHAR(20), 
     Data VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO temp.dbo.Table1
VALUES
(1001,  1333,   'OP','20011505','19952012','OP2001156519952012'),
(1002,  1245,   'OR','20121005',NULL,'OR20121005'),
(1003,  1116,   'OP','20131215',NULL,'OP20131215'),
(1004,  1234,   'OP','20011505','19952012','OP2001156519952012')    

CREATE TABLE temp.dbo.Table2
(
     CID INT,
     PID INT,
     SSC VARCHAR(3),
     StartDate VARCHAR(20),
     EndDate VARCHAR(20), 
     Data VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO temp.dbo.Table2
VALUES
(1001,  1333,   'OP','20111015',NULL,'OP20111015'),
(1002,  1245,   'OR','20131005',NULL,'OR20131005'),
(1003,  1116,   'OP','20131415',NULL,'OP2013141520131516'),
(1004,  1235,   'OP','20121015',NULL,'OP20121015')
```

Here is a screenshot of sample data which has null values where this procedure will be used to update it. The table 1 and two are joined so this is both tables together

[image]

Comment: Why bother updating StartDate? You only want to update the value when the value in the table is NULL. But you are only updating the row when it matches the value of the parameter (it will NOT return a match when either side is NULL). And for that matter, why bother with the exists? Just add both predicates to the update. No need to hit the same row once to see if it exists and then get it again to update it.

Comment: Same comment **again**: ***WHY*** are you storing dates as `nvarchar`? This is a really bad practice -- use the **most appropriate** datatype always, and for a date, it's certainly **NOT** `nvarchar` - use `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` to handle these!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ISNULL` logic is backwards. First, if `@StartDate IS NULL`, then the `EXISTS` will return `FALSE` and the `UPDATE` will not run which is correct. But, the backwards part is in the `UPDATE`. Here you want `StartDate = ISNULL(StartDate,@StartDate)` which will set it to the variable, if it `IS NULL` for that row.

This needs to be changed for the other columns as well.

```
   UPDATE temp.dbo.TABLE1
    SET StartDate = ISNULL(StartDate,@StartDate)
        ,EndDate = ISNULL(EndDate,@EndDate)
        ,Data = ISNULL(Data,@Data)
    WHERE TABLE1.SSC = 'OP'
```

Answer (score 2):

you have the variable in the wrong spot.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[Learning]

   @StartDate       nvarchar(20) = null,
   @EndDate         nvarchar(20) = null,
   @Data            nvarchar(20) = null

AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) T1.CID  FROM temp.dbo.TABLE1 AS T1 WHERE StartDate = @StartDate)
BEGIN
    UPDATE temp.dbo.TABLE1
    SET StartDate = ISNULL(StartDate,@StartDate)
        ,EndDate = ISNULL(EndDate,@EndDate)
        ,Data = ISNULL(Data,@Data)
    WHERE TABLE1.SSC = 'OP'
```